# automatic install of apk

Tags: android

I'd like to know if it is possible to trigger programmatically the installation of an apk that is on the card ?

Comment: No , I plan to update my application in this way. Download the new apk from my website and then install it automatically .

Comment: Is that how things already work? If a user has "Install non-market applications" option checked, they just browse to the download link and upon successful download the application is auto-installed?

Comment: no need to browse, just click an "update" button, receive a download link , use Android browser to download the new apk, and then install it , or at least that's what I plan. The auto installed option would be super ,but I'm not really sure that's how it works

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

(courtesy of [anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=23928))

Comment: sometimes it works , sometimes it reports it could not find the AndroidManifest file and cancels the instalation

Comment: That suggests that perhaps you are calling `startActivity()` before the downloaded APK is fully flushed to the flash or something. I would try implementing this one step at a time, starting with using `startActivity()` on an APK you manually put on the SD card (e.g., adb push, DDMS File Manager, mount/drag/unmount from your development machine). Once that is working the way you want, blend in the download mechanism.

Comment: Indeed that's the case I'm talking about . However I observed that if the apk is in the sdcard/download it is installed , but if put in the sdcard if will generate this error



04-15 16:51:02.686: ERROR/filemap(215): mmap(0,0) failed: Invalid argument
04-15 16:51:02.686: WARN/zipro(215): Unable to map '/sdcard/myapk.apk': Invalid argument
04-15 16:51:02.695: DEBUG/asset(215): failed to open Zip archive '/sdcard/myapk.apk'
04-15 16:51:02.695: DEBUG/filemap(215): munmap(0x0, 0) failed

even if the path is :INFO/mytag(196): instalation path is : ///sdcard/myapk.apk

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody is looking for this info....
If you want to install an apk which you also programmatically downloaded and stored in your private "files" folder (ie. "/data/data/com.yourapp.name/files"), you need to get the uri for the full path by first using getFileStreamPath as follows:

```
File fullPath = getFileStreamPath("name_of_downloaded_app.apk");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fullPath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help:  [install Apk via Intent](http://www.androidsnippets.info/snippets/98/). Not sure if this is the way to go though.

Comment: have you used this before ? if so please specify what "package", "xxx"
refer to in ?

Uri installUri = Uri.fromParts("package", "xxx", null);