# Android Load and run apk file on sdcard

Tags: android, apk, sd-card

I have found that some app can load a third part app exist in sdcart just decompression the apk file and run...   but I can not finger out how to ...

some body know and give me a help?  thanks...

Answer (score 1):

you can install and run the .apk file from your application like below

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),  "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
      startActivity(intent);
```

you can fine more information on this in the following link.   http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=23928 and [automatic install of apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637957/automatic-install-of-apk)

Comment: no  no  no ...  I do not want to install the app, instate, the apk file in the sdcard and I want to use like "reflection" or so to start an app at running time...