# Is this possible like auto install the apk file after downloading from server?

Tags: android, mobile, installation, webserver, apk

I need to install the apk file from server. Its downloading when i connect to the server. But after downloading, its not automatically install into the mobile. Is this possible like auto install the apk file after downloading it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637957/automatic-install-of-apk

Comment: @ anothem, Thanks for your comment. Is this only possible through programmatically?

Comment: @ anothem, I think that code used for install the application from another application. Right?

Comment: apologies, you are right, that will not solve your problem. I agree with Yury, I don't think it's generally possible to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, automatically you cannot install apk file. You can simply call package installer that will ask a user to install apk. If it were not in this way, then a malicious application would have possibility to install malicious applications without user's consent.

Meanwhile, if you're an author of ROM on which this application should run then you can add the functionality of automatic installation to your modified framework. But in general case this is impossible.

Comment: You automatically download apk and start an Intent to install the application. But the user have to agree to install this application manually (give an explicit consent to install the applications and accept permissions).

Comment: @ Yury, How to achieve this? How to start the intent for installation?

Comment: There is a link in the comment to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637957/automatic-install-of-apk

Comment: After you've downloaded apk you should write it to tmp storage and instead of fileName use the path to this stored apk file.

Comment: @ Yury, Can I need to create another application for this?

Comment: But as I understand from your question you have an application that downloads apk from a server. So in this application you can realize the installation logic.

Comment: @ Yury, Currently I don't have an application for downloading the apk from server. In the server, I was uploaded all my applications. If user connect to the server, the apk file automatically downloaded. After that user needs to install manually. So that's why I'm asking auto install of my application after downloading it.

Comment: This means that we actually did not understand your question correctly. But how do you assume a user connects to your server?

Comment: @ Yury, They can use mobile browser/email. I have sending the server address to client through email.

Comment: In this case only if a user opens the downloaded apk the package installer will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if app was third party you have to update or install manually but if your app is a google app or a known source app you can set it to install automatically